# JS/Jquery conditional without recalling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I am curious to know if it is possible to make a function's conditional statement output the result at any time the argument is true, without having to recall the function.

An example of the statement:

```
if($('#a').val() == $('#b').val()) {
     alert("A & B Match");   
}
```

I understand i could recall the function each time the elements change, but is there any way to have the alert occur at ANY time that the two elements values match, without having to recall the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll either to check the condition on an interval or through an event listener like this:

```
$('#a, #b').change(checkEqual);

function checkEqual() {
    if($('#a').val() == $('#b').val()) {
         alert("A & B Match");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thats what i thought. Event listener it is then for me, many thanks.

Comment: @StuartWickenden Sure thing. Potentially you could do some sort of abstraction for checking this condition, but it would be working off an interval or event handling situation either way. Good luck!